# AWS Step Function cost calculation for parallel tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am trying to calculate the cost of my AWS Step Function statemachine.
I get that each state transition costs a price x but I am not quite sure how transitions are calculated when it comes to parallel tasks.

Let's say I have 3 individual tasks in a parallel task. Clearly that would count as at least 3 state transitions but does the transition to the parallel task come on top of that? Also: does the transition out of the parallel task only count as one transition?

I could unfortunately not find documentation that clearly answers my question.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Pricing Example #2: Application Workflow with Multiple Paths](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/#Pricing_Example_#2:_Application_Workflow_with_Multiple_Paths), it looks like the cost for Parallel tasks are:

- Transition from previous state into the parallel state
- Transition from parallel state into each branch
- Transition out of the parallel

So for your 3 parallel states, you would be charged for 5 transitions

- 1 from previous state into parallel state
- 3 from parallel into branches
- 1 out of parallel state

IMHO this is not very clear as to what's being charged where. But if you think of it as each state transition is a cost. Into a parallel is one change, then within the parallel each branch is another and finally out of the parallel into another state.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it does sound conclusive this way

Comment: based on the updated example on the step function website, this appears to be the correct